# How do I create a column in psyspark based on the values of two existing columns?

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Pyspark data frame structured as follows.

```
| orderid  |  sub | filter-list                          | 
| -------- | ---- |          --------                    |
| 1        | 367  | [['123','supply'],['367','price']]   |
| 2        | 389  | [['389','supply'],['906','supply']]  |
| 3        | 804  | [['173','supply'],['804','price']]   |
```

In this DataFrame, I aim to extract values from the filter_list column, where the integer value of the list corresponds to the sub present in the second column.

For instance, considering the first row, the second column's value 367 is present in the 2nd position of the list that is present in the 3rd column, so the desired value i want is price.
Similarly, in the second row, the value of sub is present in the 1st position of the list in the 3rd column. Hence, the desired value is supply.

Hence the final dataframe i want is

```
| orderid  |  sub   | filter-list                             |filter-name| 
| -------- | -----  |     --------                            |   ------  |
| 1        | 367    | [['123','supply'],['367','price']]      |price      |   
| 2        | 389    | [['389','supply'],['906','supply']]     |supply     |   
| 3        | 804    | [['173','supply'],['804','price']]      |price      |
```

How can I achieve this specifically with pyspark functionality?

I've been trying various approaches without success. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: have you tried anything and can us show your attempt please

Answer (score 1):

After multiple attempts, I successfully implemented a solution using PySpark.

The key to achieving this was utilizing the TRANSFORM function along with the FILTER function, allowing me to efficiently filter and transform data as needed.

Here is the code snippet that adds a new column as desired.

```
# Extract filter-name based on conditions
df = df.withColumn(
    "filter_name",
    expr("TRANSFORM(FILTER(filter_list, f -> f[0] = CAST(sub AS STRING)), f -> f[1])[0]")
)

df.show(truncate=False)
```